# How to make the Dojo Toolkit combobox to select multiple options (multi select)

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I am using the [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) combo box, and I want to do multi-select using the Dojo combo box. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `dijit/form/ComboBox` support single selection.

Instead if you need multi selection consider using:

```
dijit.form.MultiSelect
```

Example:

```
<select data-dojo-type="dijit.form.MultiSelect" id="colors" name="colors" size="10">
  <option value="RED">Red</option>
  <option value="BLUE">Blue</option>
  <option value="GREEN" selected>Green</option>
</select>

dojo.require("dijit.form.MultiSelect");
```

More information can be found here:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/MultiSelect.html